# Webbrowser: memory leaks

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, mfc, webbrowser-control, taskmanager

I have an app developed 5 or more years ago. It is implemented using C++, MFC.
Program automates working with some web resource. The issue is that it has lof ot memory leaks.
I'm monitoring memory usage in Task Manager. And it shows me it took 150-200 Mbytes whereas Windows alerts about Virtual Memory is too low. There are no any other app running and I'm sure it because of this app.

How can I get real memory size in use with that app?

I'm getting that info with the following function: GetProcessMemoryInfo.
The quick workaround was to restart app itself, so leaked memory would freed. Unfortunately it show me the same as I see in the Task Manager (150-200Mb) which is not true...

Please advice..
Thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use VMMap http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/dd535533

It should show you everything related to memory consumption.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look on CRT functions
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e5ewb1h3(v=vs.80).aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x98tx3cf.aspx